# "Começarei fazer" ou "começarei a fazer"?

Tags: conjugações-perifrásticas

Dentre as duas frases abaixo, alguma é incorreta?

> "Amanhã *começarei* acordar cedo."
>
> "Amanhã *começarei* **a** acordar cedo."

A mim ambas parecem corretas, mas sinto que a primeira tem mais chances de estar errada. Este exemplo cai em alguma regra geral da língua portuguesa?

Answer (score 7):

Neste caso particular, o verbo *começar* deverá ser complementado com um gerúndio, seja na sua forma simples (ex. "acordando") ou com a preposição *a* seguido então de um verbo no infinitivo (ex. "a acordar"). O mesmo pode ser aplicado a verbos que também possam ser complementados com um gerúndio:

> "Estou a gostar da iniciativa." / "Estou gostando da iniciativa."

Sem esta preprosição, a frase da pergunta fica incorreta no português comum.