# A palavra "mingar" pode ser usada formalmente?

Tags: significado, expressões, verbos, significado-em-contexto

"Os dias estão a mingar" igual a "os dias estão a diminuir".
Em certas zonas de Portugal as expressões são equivalentes.

Comment: Por que não poderia?

Comment: Este me parece um caso de busca ao dicionário. Se as palavras são sinônimas, podem ser utilizadas com o mesmo valor semântico.

Comment: A dúvida pode ser sanada nesta questão: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/41/come%c3%a7arei-fazer-ou-come%c3%a7arei-a-fazer/151#151

Comment: @zewill Não percebo a ligação dessa pergunta com a resposta do teu link.

Comment: Bom dia! Também penso que são questões destintas.

Comment: @ClMend, estás perguntando quão formal *mingar* é? Eu não entendi a tua pergunta.

Comment: Exacto. Onde moro tem um caris não formal. Sera ?!

Comment: @ClMend, segundo o Priberam, *mingar* é uma forma **popular** de *minguar*, então, é informal.

Comment: @Schilive então existe o mingar e o minguar. Parece-me uma boa resposta